# The first demo of Spring boot cannot run with java1.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, tomcat8

when I change the pom.xml java.version to 1.7, it works under tomcat8

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version> 
</properties>
```

but with java8, she gives error like this(omitted the middle of the content, just show the first and last):

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_40]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

the last:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have not modified anthing, just new project with ItelliJ IDEA and run.
Although it works with jdk7, I want to know how to run it with jdk8 under tomcat8.

Comment: You didn't show the entire stack trace, but most likely, you already have something open on that port (8080 by default).

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by using the newest version 1.8.0_121 in oracle.com, not the version 1.8.0_40 in my project.Thank you very much.